# Send mail every N days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I need to send a warning mail 14 days before certificates valid_to date ends and also send email every 3 days from delay_days.

Table Certificates consists of:

```
ID(int) | cert_valid_to(date) | warn_before_days(int) | delay_days(int)
1       | '2019-09-30'        | 14                    | 3
```

First email I can send via this select

```
select datediff(day, getdate(), c.cert_valid_to) = warn_before_days
from xyz.certificates c
```

I need to extend my select with *delay_days(int)* but don't know how yet. I think it could be done with modulo operation.

Comment: Does the script run every day?

Comment: It runs nonstop. I just need to extend my select.

Comment: What do you mean nonstop? A query that never finishes running doesn't sound good.

Comment: send a mail every 3 days until the cert_valid_to date changes, or only one time 14 days before and one time 3 days after?

Comment: I mean script which is monitoring certificate's presence. It checks every day but query takes few mili seconds.

Comment: Send a mail 14 days before certificate ends(I did it and it works) and then every 3 days until the cert_valid_to date changes.

Comment: Do you have a table to log when you send emails? That would make things a lot simpler and less brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
DECLARE @today AS DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

SELECT *
FROM xyz.certificates
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, @today, cert_valid_to) <= warn_before_days
AND (warn_before_days - DATEDIFF(DAY, @today, cert_valid_to)) % delay_days = 0
```

[DB Fiddle with tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=03e7fd6d6853dc3b4e4ad5cea4d368ed)

Answer (score 2):

If I get you correctly. You done the `non stop` query with job right? You just want to know how to check the email with your criteria.

Try this :

```
select *
from xyz.certificates c
where datediff(day, getdate(), c.cert_valid_to) >= warn_before_days
and datediff(day, getdate(), c.cert_valid_to) % c.delay_days = 0
```

% mean modulus, meaning `getdate()` return true every `delay_days`.